# Bloquear vista previa de impresión en chrome en windows

Tags: chrome

Necesito bloquear la vista previa de impresión de Chrome. Ya probé varias opciones que encontré pero ninguna me ha funcionado. Hay que tener en cuenta que la versión de chrome es la 88, y el sistema operativo es windows 10.

La opción de `--disable-print-preview` NO funciona, y `chrome://flags` ya no tiene la opción de  desactivarlo.

Así que dsps de días de dar vueltas buscando, vengo a preguntar a ver si alguien tiene la respuesta mágica!!

Comment: Quieres bloquear solo en tu máquina o en algunas? Me imagino que tratas de bloquear un reporte de algún sistema; y si utilizan otro navegador?

Comment: Es en una máquina específica. Es para que lo usen las personas que quieran imprimir un pdf, pero evitar la descarga del mismo, x eso quiero bloquear la vista previa, ya que da la posibilidad de descarga. Quiero que directamente aparezca la ventana de impresión del sistema. No deberían utilizar otro navegador, ya que sólo estaría instalado chrome en el ordenador, y el uso de la máquina es sólo ese, buscar e imprimir PDF.